# Creating a derived table that contains only rows that have changed from the last run

Tags: mysql

I have a hierarchy table that needs to update a SalesForce instance via their API. The issue is we're required to update one row at a time. I'd like to prevent the API from encountering a record that has not changed since the last time the job ran.

Is there a clever way to create a table that checks if any of the values in a row has changed? And, if so, insert that row? I can then point the API at this table which will only consist of records that have changed.

For example, the base table on Day 1:

```
PersonID    Territory   Division
1           AZ1         Arizona
2           CA1         California
3           AZ1         Arizona
```

And the base table on Day 2:

```
PersonID    Territory   Division
1           AZ1         Arizona
2           CA2         California
3           AZ1         Arizona
```

The only value that changed between day 1 and day 2 is row 2.

Desired derived table:

```
PersonID    Territory   Division
2           CA2         California
```

Comment: You could add triggers that mark rows as changed or copy them or their ID into another table or similar. Or maybe just a timestamp in the table that reflects the last change.

Comment: Add two triggers, **BEFORE INSERT**, and **BEFORE UPDATE**. Add a column that stores the current timestamp called *modified*. Your triggers will update this column with the current timestamp. When you run your query to get the data, select rows where the *modified* column's date is greater than the last time you ran the query.